# Type error while calculating numpy array mean

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to perform linear discriminant analysis using a code given below

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('Hazara1.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')
feature_dict = {i:label for i,label in zip(
            range(15), ("DYS19","DYS389I","DYS389II","DYS390","DYS391","DYS392","DYS393","DYS437","DYS438","DYS439","DYS448","DYS456","DYS458","DYS635","Y_GATA_H4",))}
df.columns = [l for i,l in sorted(feature_dict.items())] + ['class label']
df.dropna(how="all", inplace=True)
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
X = df[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]].values
y = df['class label'].values
enc = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder = enc.fit(y)
y = label_encoder.transform(y) + 1
label_dict = {1: 'Central_Asia', 2: 'South_Asia',  3:'Russia',4:'East_Asia',5:'Hazara'} 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
np.set_printoptions(precision=15)
mean_vectors = []
for cl in range(1,6):
    mean_vectors.append(np.mean(X[y==cl], axis=0))
```

Where **df** contains data as shown [here](http://dpaste.com/3PHMWNN).
But when I execute the above code I get following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "iris2.py", line 30, in <module>
 mean_vectors.append(np.mean(X[y==cl], axis=0))
 File "/home/ammar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy  /core/fromnumeric.py", line 2878, in mean
 out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
 File "/home/ammar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 65, in _mean
 ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is in your `y` vector? Are the values strings?

Comment: `>>> y
array([1, 1, 1, ..., 3, 3, 3])
>>> type(y)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: Looks like your X array has some strings along with numbers in it, check it.

Comment: @SFTP how can I check for the presence of string in a numpy array or X?

Comment: The mistake was in my excel file that I was reading in pandas dataframe. Two values are present together in few fields separated by comma and these fields were saved as characters in numpy array. I changed the values and now it works fine.  @SFTP thanks for your comment.